# Debugging-Editing JavaScript files of App's in Gaia-Firefox OS doesn't reflect in the simulator

Tags: javascript, firefox-os, gaia

I have Mozilla Firefox browser 35.0.1 with App Manager tool in the browser.

I installed Firefox OS Simulator 2.0 in the App manager.

There are 2 tabs here, in the tool -**Apps and devices**

Here in my problem, I choose the CLOCK app. I had some breakpoints and print statements to debug the CLOCK app.
After doing the changes, I saved the CLOCK's Java script files.

I go back to my Firefox simulator in my browser, selected **"Add Packaged app"** and added my modified java script file.
Here i get a notification in my simulator, that my CLOCK app is installed. [image]![1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muyA9.jpg)http://postimg.org/image/903alf1wf/

But i don't see the modifications that i made. If I open the currently installed clock app (which i modified), its blank as shown here [image]![2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PNjb.jpg)http://postimg.org/image/w3bezsy3v/

Is there anything I'm missing here or is there any other way to edit the java script files and see the changes reflected in my simulator immediately?

I m a beginner in Gaia development.

Comment: This question tries to adress the same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691059/how-to-debug-javascript-file-on-firefox-os-device
But I am using a simulator.

Comment: You have to use the WebIDE and before that, you might have to root and get admin privileges on firefoxOS

Comment: Please tell me how to get admin privileged on firefoxOS.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clock is an inbuilt app. You don't need to install this app. It's a pre-installed app.
Are you using GAIA source code? If not, then please clone the GAIA repo from [Github](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia). After cloning, make changes to clock app (present in apps folder) and build your GAIA source code. Refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developing_Gaia/Making_Gaia_code_changes).

If you are building GAIA source code on windows, you might face some issues. Follow the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326405/unable-to-build-gaia-from-git-in-windows-getting-makefile671-recipe-for-targ/32298888#32298888).